# Why would useRef object be null even after attaching to a div element?

Tags: reactjs, dom, infinite-scroll, use-ref, swr

Hey yall Im having a weird and annoying issue while trying to useRef on a div element. I have this working exactly as it is on another page but this doesnt seem to be doing what I want it to on this page.

Im trying to implement and endless scroll. The goal is to attach the ref (refetchTrigger) to a certain div on the page and have that trigger a fetch for the next page of data when scrolled into view. It seems to render the div correctly but refetchTrigger is not updated to be the div, it just remains null. Seems like a rerender needs to happen here but obviously changes to refs dont trigger a rerender. Ive been battling with this all morning and would greatly appreciate any suggestions. In the code snippet below, all console.log(refetchTrigger.current) are printing out null.

Its also worth noting that the refetch call is using useSWR hook to fetch data. when removing this the attaching of ref to div seemed to work correctly. also, when adding a button to fetch its fetching as expected. its just trying when trying to automatically trigger the fetch that Im seeing the issue.

Thanks for the help!

```
export const TrackGrid = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState<Track[]>([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState<number>(1);
  const refetchTrigger = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const inViewport = useIntersection(refetchTrigger, "0px");

  const { tracks, error, isValidating } = useGetTracks(false, page, 20);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inViewport) {
      setPage(page + 1);
    }

    console.log("in viewport");
  }, [inViewport]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (tracks) setList([...list, ...tracks]);
  }, [tracks]);

  const renderDiv = () => {
    console.log(refetchTrigger.current);
    const d = <div ref={refetchTrigger}>exists</div>;
    console.log(refetchTrigger.current);
    return d;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="grid place-items-center grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-4">
        {!!list.length && renderDiv()}

        {list.map((track: Track, i: number) => {
          console.log(refetchTrigger.current);
          return (
            <div ref={refetchTrigger} key={i}>
              <TrackGridItem track={track} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here is the code thats interacting with the ref

````
```export const useIntersection = (element: any, rootMargin: string) => {
  const [isVisible, setState] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      ([entry]) => {
        setState(entry.isIntersecting);
      },
      { rootMargin }
    );

    element.current && observer.observe(element.current);

    return () => element.current && observer.unobserve(element.current);
  }, []);

  return isVisible;
};```
````

Answer (score 1):

The ref only gets populated *after* the render is complete, and the element has been created by react on the actual dom. Logging the ref out during the render will not work (unless there has been a previous render).

The fix is to put your code that needs to interact with the ref into a `useEffect`. That way by the time your code runs, the render is complete and the element is on the page.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(refetchTrigger.current)
}, []);
```

Comment: He needs `useLayoutEffect`. The ref will be null here on mount if he uses `useEffect`

Comment: `He needs useLayoutEffect` He might, yes, but that would be to prevent a flicker, not because the ref will have a null. The ref will be non-null in a useEffect (assuming he passes the ref into some element that gets put on the page, eg `<div ref={refetchTrigger}>`)

Comment: `useEffect` works with refs yes, but in your example you have a `useEffect` that runs on mount. If this is a ref used for DOM elements (i.e. attached to the ref attribute) there are no circumstances where on first mount it wont be null. But he could do null checks to get around it of course. "It depends" as always.

Comment: When do you think that `useEffect` runs? The order is: the component renders, then react updates the dom and refs, then effects run.

Comment: Sorry but thats not right. Component renders != DOM is committed. `useEffect` runs before the DOM is committed.

Comment: OMG you are right! My god, I cant beleive ive been working on that false assumption. I just self-proved i was wrong on codesandbox. Nevermind and thankyou!  Obviously exception is if hes needing to run something that reads an attr on the element affected by some state change.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the ref will not be populated until after the whole render pass is finished. This is not obvious to many React programmers (and it usually doesn't matter) but the DOM is not actually committed until later on. When you call `renderDiv()` and pass the `ref`, on the first mount the element is not even rendered in the DOM at the stage that code executes. React effectively executes and renders the *virtual DOM* tree into the real DOM shortly after the render pass.

If you have code that is reliant on the DOM node existing, because you need to read something for whatever reason you need to run it an effect or (this is something you have to be careful with), run it in a ref callback.

Comment: Thank yall both for the quick responses! Maybe im not understanding the root issue here. If the ref doesnt get populated until after the render, how would I set a div as the "trigger" when it scrolls onto the screen? I dont really need to console log it, i need it to trigger a fetch when that element gets scrolled on to the screen. Are there any good examples using the callBack ref or effect ?

Comment: That'll be fine, because to do it you'll need to put a scroll handler on the window (or scroll container) and store that scroll value in state. That means that by the time you detect the intersection, it will already be populated since state updates = rerender. The reference to the element is retained on subsequent renders. BTW though intersection observer is better this because storing a scrollTop value in state will cause a hell a lot of rerenders. You want an event based notification that it entered the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was updating the useEffect to remove the dependency array. According to the new react [docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef), the recommended read or write example is in a useEffect without a dependency array (runs every time).

In my above example the ref is being used in the useIntersection hook. I removed the dependency array and it worked as expected